# Creating Sagemaker training job with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sagemaker

I am new to terraform and was looking through the documentation. From what I can tell, there's nothing in terraform with regards to create a training job that has the model artifacts. Does this mean I can't use terraform to set up the full sagemaker pipeline? It seems to me you would have to first create the training job in some way, and then you can use terraform to create a model enpoint that uses what is there (but you can't do the training job itself with terraform).

Comment: Probably make a feature request on the Terraform AWS provider Github issue tracker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more of a feature request that belongs on GitHub rather than here.

Comment: Yup, fair enough. I just wanted to double check that I wasn't overlooking something

Answer (score 1):

Neither CloudFormation nor Terraform support SageMaker training. Have you looked at Apache Airflow? It's nicely integrated with SageMaker and lets you build end-to-end pipelines:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-end-to-end-machine-learning-workflows-with-amazon-sagemaker-and-apache-airflow/